# Apache Tez build fails

Tags: hadoop, maven-3, apache-tez

I am trying to build Apache Tez (Both 0.6.1 and 0.7.0 version) for hadoop-2.6.0 in windows using below command

```
mvn clean package -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip
```

But i am getting below exception

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:exec (Bower install) @ tez-ui ---bower FileSaver.js#24b303f49213b905ec9062b708f7cd43d56a5dde           ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] tez ................................................ SUCCESS [  0.924 s]
[INFO] tez-api ............................................ SUCCESS [ 11.585 s]
[INFO] tez-common ......................................... SUCCESS [  1.421 s]
[INFO] tez-runtime-internals .............................. SUCCESS [  2.029 s]
[INFO] tez-runtime-library ................................ SUCCESS [  4.751 s]
[INFO] tez-mapreduce ...................................... SUCCESS [  2.553 s]
[INFO] tez-examples ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.862 s]
[INFO] tez-dag ............................................ SUCCESS [  8.363 s]
[INFO] tez-tests .......................................... SUCCESS [  2.044 s]
[INFO] tez-ui ............................................. FAILURE [  3.105 s]
[INFO] tez-plugins ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-yarn-timeline-history .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-yarn-timeline-history-with-acls ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-mbeans-resource-calculator ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-tools .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-dist ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Tez ................................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 38.169 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-13T15:07:23+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 76M/1049M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:exec (Bower install) on project tez-ui: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :tez-ui
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error, it seems like you need git installed:

> ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH

Also, this might be helpful for other errors: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TEZ/Build+errors+and+solutions

Comment: I have build it without superuser permission by following in that link. It worked. Thanks.

Comment: I installed git using 'sudo apt-get install git' and then it worked for me as i build it without superuser permission.

Answer (score 1):

Once look at this... this may help you.
**Reason**: You are running as root or with superuser permissions.

**Solutions**:

**Recommended**: Run without superuser permission, or as a non-root user.

**Alternate**: If you want to continue as root, add --allow-root to arguments tag of exec-maven-plugin in tez-ui/pom.xml.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. I have did without superuser permission.

Answer (score 0):

Like hadoop_user proposed, I would firstly check this [website](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TEZ/Build+errors+and+solutions) and try all the fixes but with one remark: in 3rd fix (clearing folder node_tmp) - if you cannot find that folder try clearing the following folder: $TEZ_PATH/tez-X.Y.Z/ tez-ui/src/main/webapp/node_modules/

I tried deleting that folder once I tried everything else and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Install git, node & npn. This worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Installing git, node and npm worked for me as well.Before building install all the three and try to run the mvn package -DskipTests.This works.